# Bootstrap Pop up Over unity Web Player

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, unity-game-engine

I want to show bootstrap modal pop up over unity web player in a web browser but when i click on button and pop up appears, pop up data is not visible over unity web player, it is hidden behind the player.

how i make it is visible over unity web player, is this possible? if not, is there any other way to show a html page/div as pop up on button click?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but because of how the browser render the 3D of the Unity package, it will always be place on top of anything.

What you can do though is send commands from Unity to your webpage, so you can have a "modal" in Unity and send whatever command you need to your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class

```
.modal {
    z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

to your css file.